# Unmarshal a nested OPML Document

Tags: go, opml

I am trying to unmarshal a simple nested opml document. The problem comes when I have nested opml and I am unable to decide on structure. I am putting the code below. Please let me know how can I parse the multi level of nesting of the `Outline` struct.

http://play.golang.org/p/FobiL1JDdb

```
    package main

    import (
        "encoding/xml"
        "fmt"
    )

    var response = `<opml version='1.0'>
     <head>
      <title>More Cases</title>
      <expansionState>1,6,26</expansionState>
     </head>
     <body>
      <outline text='Testing' _note='indeterminate'>
       <outline text='Weekly' _status='indeterminate'>
       </outline>
       </outline>
     </body>
    </opml>`

    type Opml struct {
        XMLName xml.Name
        Version string `xml:"version,attr"`
        Head    Head   `xml:"head"`
        Body    Body   `xml:"body"`
    }

    type Head struct {
        Title          string `xml:"title"`
        ExpansionState string `xml:"expansionState"`
    }

    type Body struct {
        Outline Outline `xml:"outline"`
    }
    type Outline struct {
        Text string `xml:"text,attr"`
        Note string `xml:"_note,attr"`
    }

    func main() {

        fmt.Println("UnMrashal XML")
        opml := &Opml{}
        xml.Unmarshal([]byte(response), opml)
        fmt.Println(opml)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need use pointer

```
type Outline struct {
    Text string `xml:"text,attr"`
    Note string `xml:"_note,attr"`
    Outline *Outline `xml:"outline"`
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/f1UqEkJq4S